# Is the NCAlgebra package broken?

Tags: ncalgebra

Just for fun I downloaded and installed the NCAlgebra package.
However upon running the NCTEST suite I got the following right off the bat:

> SUMMARY OF TESTS

- 22 files tested.
- 1822 tests completed in 2.81575 seconds.
- 1819 succeeded.
- 3 failed.

SetCommutingOperators::AlreadyDefined: Symbols y and x were already defined commutative. Replacing existing rule.

TagUnset::norep: Assignment on y for NonCommutativeMultiply`Private`c___**y**x**NonCommutativeMultiply`Private`d___ not found.

TagUnset::norep: Assignment on x for NonCommutativeMultiply`Private`c___**y**x**NonCommutativeMultiply`Private`d___ not found.

- Test #120 failed. Result:

  True

  differs from correct answer:

  False
- Test #121 failed. Result:

  True

  differs from correct answer:

  False

SetCommutingOperators::AlreadyDefined: Symbols y and x were already defined commutative. Replacing existing rule.

TagUnset::norep: Assignment on y for NonCommutativeMultiply`Private`c___**y**x**NonCommutativeMultiply`Private`d___ not found.

General::stop: Further output of TagUnset::norep will be suppressed during this calculation.

- Test #130 failed. Result:

  True

  differs from correct answer:

  False

> END NCTEST

> EVEN IF ALL THE TESTS SUCCEEDED YOU SHOULD QUIT THE KERNEL

IN YOUR MATHEMATICA SESSION AND START OVER.

Is anyone on here familiar with this package? And if so am I getting something others see or not?

Comment: You can ask [here](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/issues).

Comment: It is not like it cannot break. https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/commit/73d945c23f557912b6236394b04be0da9ed586f2

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you did not had a clean kernel when you ran the test. The complaint about x and y already been defined is a teller. Please quit the kernel before running the tests.

Comment: Hi, I thought that but I had quit the kernel before running the tests. And I just a few minutes ago tried again - it failed the same way.

Comment: What version Mathematica and OS?

Comment: I was thinking this might be along the lines of the problem. $Version gives "13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"

Comment: I have download v.13.0.0 of Mathematica and I cannot reproduce your testing results. I still think you do not have a clean Kernel. Do you have anything on init.m or other initialization files? What happens when you type `? x` before running the tests? If you still have the issue please submit a detailed report on the github repo. https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/issues

Comment: I do have a clean kernel. But are you running on a Apple Silicon Mac? ? x gives Missing["UnknownSymbol", "x"] before the test. After the tests it gives 
   HoldPattern[CommutativeQ[x]] ^= False

Comment: I have made various upgrades and bumped the version to 5.0.5. I think your issues are gone in this new version. Please give it a try. If they are still present please report an issue at the github repo.

Comment: Yep - it works now - all tests passed. Were the problems related to Apple Silicon?

Comment: There were a variety of problems that were related to recent Mathematica upgrades. Every upgrade is a roller coaster ride! NCAlgebra is such a complex package that minor changes in obscure functions can have an impact. What was causing what you were seeing was a change in the default behavior of the ValueQ function that got rolled out in the 12.2 update. Fortunately it only affected the behavior of the tests, not any major functionality. I took the chance to roll out many more upgrades that were in the works in the development version to put them into the latest release.

Comment: I can well believe Mathematica upgrades lead to broken functionality and being a royal PITA. Thanks for you efforts, it is much appreciated.